# How to import and create time series data frames in an efficient way?

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I have many separate data files in csv format for a lot of daily stock prices. Over a few years there are hundreds of those data files, whose names are the dates of data record.

In each file there are variables of ticker (or stock trading code), date, open price, high price, low price, close price, and trading volume. For example, inside a data file named `20150128.txt` it looks like this:

`FB,20150128,1.075,1.075,0.97,0.97,725221
AAPL,20150128,2.24,2.24,2.2,2.24,63682
AMZN,20150128,0.4,0.415,0.4,0.415,194900
NFLX,20150128,50.19,50.21,50.19,50.19,761845
GOOGL,20150128,1.62,1.645,1.59,1.63,684835
...................and many more..................`

In case it's relevant, the number of stocks in these files are not necessarily  the same (so there will be missing data). I need to import and create 5 separate time series data frames from those files, one each for Open, High, Low, Close and Volume. In each data frame, rows are indexed by date, and columns by ticker. For example, the data frame Open may look like this:

`DATE,FB,AAPL,AMZN,NFLX,GOOGL,...
20150128,1.5,2.2,0.4,5.1,1.6,...
20150129,NA,2.3,0.5,5.2,1.7,...
...`

What will be an efficient way to do that? I've used the following codes to read the files into a list of data frames but don't know what to do next from here.

`files = list.files(pattern="*.txt")
mydata = lapply(files, read.csv,head=FALSE)`

EDIT: I managed to get this work (not sure about the downvote though)

`files = list.files(pattern="*.txt")`
`df = ldply(files, read_csv,col_names=c("ticker","date","open","high", "low", "close", "volume"))`

Answer (score 1):

This might be more convenient using `purrr` and `readr`:

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata <- files %>% 
  map_dfr(read_csv)
```

This way, you'll get a single `tibble`, rather than a list of data frames.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion but for some reason it didn't work. I got it done in a probably less efficient way (updated edits)

Comment: Cool that you could solve it yourself! I haven't used `ldply` but of course there are multiple ways of solving this. If you care to get to the bottom of the issue with `map_dfr` you can post the error msg here. Otherwise, have a nice day, @NonSleeper :)